# How to submit multiple forms in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a simple form which contains a button to open another form in a pop up modal, the form looks like this

[image]

Now as you can see above prebids input plus button, when the user clicks the plus  button it opens the modal which contains a form like this below.

[image]

Now I want to submit the forms in the following an order

```
First submit: base form (norma way)

Second submit: form inside a pop up (via ajax)
```

Here is my store function to submit the forms in a page controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $page = Page::create([
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'articles' => $request->get('articles'),
            'status' => $request->get('status'),
        ]);

        // dd($request);
        $page->save();

        $bidder = Bidder::create('page_id' -> $page->id);

        // save bidders informtion to the database using ajax
        if($request->ajax())
        {
         $rules = array(
          'params_name.*'  => 'required',
          'params_value.*'  => 'required',
          'bidders_name.*'  => 'required',

         );
         $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
         if($error->fails())
         {
          return response()->json([
           'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
          ]);
         }

          $params_name = $request->params_name;
          $params_value =$request->params_value;
          $bidders_name =$request->bidders_name;

         for($count = 0; $count < count($params_name); $count++)
         {
          $data = array(
           'params_name'   => $params_name[$count],
           'params_value'  => $params_value[$count],
           'bidders_name'  => $bidders_name[$count],


          );
          $insert_data[] = $data; 
         }

         bidder_parameters::insert($insert_data);

         return response()->json([
          'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
         ]);
        }
        return redirect("/pages")->with("sucess", "data saved");
    }
```

And here is ajax for submitting form inside a pop up

```
  $("#paramsForms").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/pages',
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:function() {
            $("#save").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('Data successfull saved');
        },
        error:function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          console.log('Data not saved');
        }
    })   
})
```

Now when I click submit I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `pages` (`title`, `articles`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, 2019-11-06 11:29:31, 2019-11-06 11:29:31))"
```

Note: checking dd($request) for both forms in a store function, I get the following

```
+request: ParameterBag {#44
    #parameters: array:4 [
      "_token" => "Wgozk9jnyUnJkL35vPhso9sUr7lbMD8cSgMVuN2s"
      "bidders_name" => array:1 [
        0 => "Biden"
      ]
      "params_name" => array:1 [
        0 => "democratic"
      ]
      "params_value" => array:1 [
        0 => "10"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Note: The problem is when I click submit on pop modal it try to send the base form at first

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: Decide whether you want `title` as a mandatory field

Comment: It seems you're not sending the title with your request, and it's required for your inserts. You should consider validating requests before attempting to insert

Comment: Are you sure that there is a problem with Laravel itself? What have you tried to narrow the problem further down?

Comment: The problem is when I click submit button on pop modal it try to send the base form that is why I am getting the error, now I want the best way to send these forms @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

**Note: The problem is when I click submit on pop modal it try to send the base form at first**

It means laravel is treating your both form as one and when u try to submit the pop up form it submited the base form. Please make sure you both form are separated.
There might possible that u have not close one of the form tag and the save changes button of pop up form is acting as the base form submit button.